# Android Animation with Gridviews: Scaling from a thumbnail to a full-size image

Tags: android, android-animation

I currently have a `GridView` filled with thumbnail images. Now normally I'd load the fullsize versions of these thumbnails in a 'detail' activity via an `onClickListener`.

However I'm trying to replicate the effect where, if I click on a thumbnail, it should scale up to show  the fullsize image, and when you tap on the fullsize image it should scale back down to the thumbnail. I've tried a simple scale animation, but can't seem to get my head around animating the image from (and back to) it's initial position.

Note: If anyone has a HTC One X, the effect I'm chasing is exactly like the Gallery app on that phone. The Jellybean powered Nexus 7 also has the same effect when you click on an image.

My most recent attempt has been (fired onClick):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="200" />
```

**Update**: Tried looking at the source for Google's Gallery3D app (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/gallery3d/app), which is the one the Nexus uses, but it's massively complicated.

Comment: Scale a View is rather easy, I guess you already know how to do it. Another thing left to do is calculate the position from which to start/end the scale, you may need `View.LayoutParams`.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do that. Currently I can get the image I need to scale, but not how to scale from the selected image's dimensions to fit the screen size.

Comment: I have actually solved this to a degree. I'll write up my answer when I can.

Comment: @MoKargas Hi can you write your answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNF8pXr6whU) is a good example of similar effect in DevBytes. It is using new API in [ActivityOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html), which is available from JellyBean directly or can be accessed via [support-v4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html) library

The code snipped from that example is here:

```
Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_COLOUR, colour);
Bundle b = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(colour);
    b = ActivityOptions.makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation(view, bitmap, 0, 0).toBundle();
}
startActivity(i, b);
```